# Fragment content is overlaying Toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I recently started messing around with the new components of AppCompat 21 and implementing Material Design. Currently, I have an ActionBarActivity with a Toolbar and am trying to have it host a fragment containing a RecyclerView of TextView items (just to test out Recycler). I have items being displayed, but the text in each view is cut off and the entire Recycler is covering the Toolbar like so:

[image: e description here]

As you can see, there are three TextViews. Their text is cut off halfway and it's overlaying the Toolbar (no Title I know). The TextView item layouts are contained within a RecyclerView layout, which is the layout of the Fragment. The parent Activity has a FrameLayout -> Toolbar, FrameLayout. I am inserting the Fragment into the Activity's sub FrameLayout. Here's the XML:

Each view in the Recycler:

```
<TextView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/textview"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="48dp"
  android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
  android:paddingTop="16dp"
  android:paddingBottom="20dp"
  android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

The Recycler layout, which is the layout of the Fragment:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/recycler_tasks"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="stuff.MainActivity$TaskFragment">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

And the parent Activity's layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/container"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity"
  tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I know it must be something simple but I've been stumped on it for a while, trying various things to no avail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `RelativeLayout` instead of `FrameLayout` as top parent. Then just add dependencies like `layout_above` for the `Toolbar` or `layout_below` for the fragment container.

Answer (score 22):

Please do not forget to add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your content layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```